# using Thinktecture.IdentityServer3 as a Federation Provider with transforming of claims

Tags: claims-based-identity, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

Hello I have been trying to work out how I could configure IdentityServer3 to become a multi-tenant federation provider that can transform and enrich claims coming back from say ADSF, Google+, Microsoft Account.

Does anyone have any example code of somebody trying to do the following?

```
MyWebApp(multi-tenant) <-- IdSrv3 <---- ADFS
                            ^
                            |<------- Google+
                            |<------- Microsoft Account
                            |<------- Facebook Account
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the IUserService - epeciall the AuthenticateExternalAsync method. There you receive the external claims and programmatically transform them.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/userService.html

Comment: [Cory Loriot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7965282/cory-loriot) is [stating](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43791519/5292302) that the link has been changed to https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html, please verify and update your post, you can flag this comment as obsolute when done